# how to compare Stringbuffer object and String object

Tags: java

how to compare sb and s

```
StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer("Hello");
String s= "Hello";
```

`s.equals(sb.toString())` is giving result as **false**.

Comment: it prints true for me when I run your code. Are you sure what you think is going on is actually going on?

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using by cutting and pasting. Don't retype your code here.

Comment: Try by using `equalsIgnoreCase()`, if it goes true then there is something about the casing of one of the values.

Answer (score 12):

Unable to reproduce:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer("Hello");
        String s= "Hello";
        System.out.println(s.equals(sb.toString())); // Prints true
    }
}
```

If you think the two values are *really* the same, please post a similar short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect you'll find the problem is elsewhere - such as some invisible characters in the string or StringBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely returning `true` for me. As the content of both strings (the String object you created and the String object returned by the StringBuffer `toString()`) are the same, the `equals()` method shouldn't return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It will give false, when you will able to compare without using `toString()` on StringBuffer Object.

Like:

```
     StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer("abc");
     String s1="abc";
     System.out.println("   "+s1.equals(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

use `s.contentEquals(sb);`
This will work .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10304091)

Comment: @mjp66 This does not provide an answer ... because? Since you seem to be new to this review queue please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag

Comment: @Tom You're right, I flubbed here. I often post a quick one-line answer as a comment. I flagged it as NaA as it doesn't elaborate (my mistake, I thought these types of answers were frowned upon). Thanks!

Comment: @mjp66 You have to differ between "not an answer" (something like a new question, spam or "thanks") and bad answers (incomplete or broken code snippets; wouldn't solve the problem). The first one needs flags and the second one needs comments and/or downvotes. So in this case: a comment about the missing explanation (and maybe a downvote) would be correct to "handle" this. Btw: a lot of people handle answers incorrectly, so no worries, that happens. And this is also nice to read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Equals and == will not work for comparision of StringBuffer and String.

> == will work only for comparisions among the same non-collections [ integers, characters etc.]
>
> equals method will work only for comparisons among the same
> collections [ array, string, objects etc.]

**Note : Comparisions between different collections or non-collection leads to error.**

```
class ClassName{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // STRING VS STRING BUFFER

        String strg = "Hello";
        StringBuffer strgBuf = new StringBuffer(strg);

        //if(strg == strgBuf ) //=> error: incomparable types: String and StringBuffer
        
        if(strg.equals(strgBuf)) 
            System.out.println("strg.equals(strgBuf) is true");
        else 
            System.out.println("strg.equals(strgBuf) is false") ;
        //=> strg.equals(strgBuf) is false

        // 2 STRINGS COMPARED
        if(strg.equals(strgBuf.toString())) 
            System.out.println("strg.equals(strgBuf.toString()) is true"); 
        else 
            System.out.println("strg.equals(strgBuf.toString()) is false");
        //=> strg.equals(strgBuf.toString()) is true


        // STRING BUFFER VS STRING BUFFER

        StringBuffer strgBuf2 = new StringBuffer(strg);

        if(strgBuf2 == strgBuf) 
            System.out.println("strgBuf2 == strgBuf is true");
        else 
            System.out.println("strgBuf2 == strgBuf is false") ;
        //=> strgBuf2 == strgBuf is false

        if(strgBuf2.equals(strgBuf)) 
            System.out.println("strgBuf2.equals(strgBuf) is true");
        else 
            System.out.println("strgBuf2.equals(strgBuf) is false") ;
        //=> strgBuf2.equals(strgBuf) is false
        
        // 2 STRINGS COMPARED
        if(strgBuf2.toString().equals(strgBuf.toString())) 
            System.out.println("strgBuf2.toString().equals(strgBuf.toString()) is true");
        else 
            System.out.println("strgBuf2.toString().equals(strgBuf.toString()) is false") ;
        //=> strgBuf2.toString().equals(strgBuf.toString()) is true
        

        // STRING VS STRING

        String strg2 = new String(strg);

        
        if(strg == strg2) 
            System.out.println("strg == strg2 is true");
        else 
            System.out.println("strg == strg2 is false") ;
        //=> strg == strg2 is false

        if(strg.equals(strg2)) 
            System.out.println("strg.equals(strg2) is true");
        else 
            System.out.println("strg.equals(strg2) is false") ;
        //=> strg.equals(strg2) is true
        

    }
}
```